# How to pass data from sqlite listview to new intent?

Tags: android, database, listview, data-retrieval, sqlite

(this is my lunch.class which populate the listview from database.tell me if there is any mistakes.im still new to this.)

```
 public class Lunch extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

DBOpener dbopener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //for fullscreen view
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dinner);

    dbopener = new DBOpener(this);
}

// Open the DB, query all subject codes and refresh the listview
// when app resumes
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Configure the listview
    ArrayList<String> mealNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView lstDine = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.dine);
    lstDine.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mealNames));

    // Open/create the DB
    try {
        dbopener.createDatabase(); // Create DB if necessary
      dbopener.openDatabase(); // Open the DB

      Cursor dinners = dbopener.getLunchNames();
      while (dinners.moveToNext()) {
          mealNames.add(dinners.getString(0)); // Get the current subj
                                                  // code, add to list
      }
      dinners.close();

      // Update the listview
      ArrayAdapter<String> ad = (ArrayAdapter<String>)lstDine.getAdapter();
      ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

      lstDine.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open DB", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

// Close the DB when app pauses
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    dbopener.close();
}

// When user clicks on an item
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // Use subject code from listview to retrieve other
      // details with the dbopener

    switch(pos)
    {
    case 0 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    newActivity.putExtra("1", "2"); // this is where im unaware of the codes.how to pass the strings of value to the next page
    startActivity(newActivity);
    break;
    }
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 1 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    startActivity(newActivity); 
    break;
    }
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 2 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    startActivity(newActivity);
    break;
    }
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 3 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    startActivity(newActivity);
    break;
    }
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 4 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    startActivity(newActivity);
    break;
    }
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 5 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    startActivity(newActivity);
    break;
    }
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 6 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    startActivity(newActivity);
    break;
    }
    switch(pos)
    {
    case 7 :
    Intent newActivity = new Intent("com.edu.tp.iit.mns.Display");
    startActivity(newActivity);
    break;
    }

}
```

(this is the display.class (image 2) works like a template to display dynamic info like image,food name, food description and its rating.

```
  public class Display extends Activity {

DBOpener dbopener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);   

    dbopener = new DBOpener(this);      
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Configure the listview
  //        ArrayList<String> mealNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  //        ListView lstDine = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.dine);
  //        lstDine.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
  //            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mealNames));

    // Open/create the DB
    try {
  //            dbopener.createDatabase(); // Create DB if necessary
      dbopener.openDatabase(); // Open the DB
      Toast.makeText(this, " open DB", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Cursor dinners = dbopener.getLunchNames();
      while (dinners.moveToNext()) {
  //              mealNames.add(dinners.getString(0)); // Get the current subj
                                                  // code, add to list
      }
      dinners.close();

      // Update the listview
 //       ArrayAdapter<String> ad = (ArrayAdapter<String>)lstDine.getAdapter();
  //          ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
   //               
  //          lstDine.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open DB", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

// Close the DB when app pauses
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        dbopener.close();
    }

 }
```

and lastly my dpopener file:

```
  public class DBOpener extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = 
   "/data/data/com.edu.tp.iit.mns/databases/"; //path of our database
    private static String DB_NAME ="finals"; // Database name
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public DBOpener(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    myContext = context;
}

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExists = checkDatabase();
    if (dbExists) {
        // Do nothing, DB already exists
        Log.d("DBOpener", "DB exists");
    } else {
        // By calling this method an empty database will be created
            // in the default system path of your application, which we
            // will overwrite with our own database.
        Log.d("DBOpener", "DB does not exit - copying from assets");
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copyDatabase();
        }
}


private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        // Try opening the database
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, 
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // If it fails, DB does not exist
    }
    if (checkDB != null)
        checkDB.close(); // Close the DB; we don’t need it now
    return checkDB != null;
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream istream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    // Transfer bytes from istream to ostream
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = istream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        ostream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close streams
    istream.close();
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLiteException {
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 
        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}

// Retrieve all subject codes
public Cursor getDinnerNames() {
    if (db == null)
        return null;
    return db.query("dinner", new String[] {"name"},
        null, null, null, null, null);
}


// Get details of specific subject
public Cursor getDinnerDetails(String name) {
    if (db == null)
        return null;
    return db.query("dinner", new String[] {"name", "nutrition", "rating"},
        "name = ?", new String[] {name}, null, null, null);
}

// Retrieve all subject codes
public Cursor getLunchNames() {
    if (db == null)
        return null;
    return db.query("lunch", new String[] {"name"},
        null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Get details of specific subject
    public Cursor getLunchDetails(String name) {
        if (db == null)
            return null;
        return db.query("dinner", new String[] {"name", "nutrition", "rating"},
            "name = ?", new String[] {name}, null, null, null);
    }

    // Retrieve all subject codes
    public Cursor getBreakfastNames() {
        if (db == null)
            return null;
        return db.query("breakfast", new String[] {"name"},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    // Get details of specific subject
    public Cursor getBreakfastDetails(String name) {
        if (db == null)
            return null;
        return db.query("breakfast", new String[] {"name", "nutrition", "rating"},
            "name = ?", new String[] {name}, null, null, null);
    }
   }
```

can u help me kick start with the case 0 so that i can complete the code. example, user click BBQ chicken sandwich. it will navigate to display.class and retrieve the info from db and shows image rating and stuffs.

Comment: You have a switch statement for every single case. You should have one single switch statement with many cases inside of it. Read up on how to use switch statements properly to help clean up your code.

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments to the new activity via intent you use the putExtra(), like you put on your code:
newActivity.putExtra("1", "2");

The first parameter should be an String constant to identify your parameter, you will use this String to get the value later. The second parameter is the value, android has methods for all the primitives.

On the new activity, you use getExtra("1", "2"), where 1 is the constant you used earlier and 2 is the default value, in case it doesn't finds the value or the constant you used.

Comment: thank you sir for the reply.i know what you are trying to say. but sorry for asking again. the String constant you are saying, im lost. can u take a closer look at my DPOpener file and show me which String constant am i suppose to put inside the putExtra method?

Comment: Any string will do, you just have to use the same one when putting and retrieving. Then it depends on your code, you could just pass an identifier like putExtra("com.example.TYPE", "type1") or maybe pass the query direct, like putExtra("com.example.SQLQUERY", "select * from db;").